# Handling SEO Friendly URL with Non-English Characters

Tags: mysql, seo, friendly-url, permalinks, non-english

I have URLs like this:  `.com/topic.php?id=6` I can convert them to this: `.com/topic/5.html` This works, but now I want to convert `.com/topic/title.html` The "title" is dynamic, for example `çağdaş` and can contain non-English characters like `Ş`or `Ğ` or `Ü`

In this case, I first convert characters to acceptable equivalents like `Ş` to `S` or `Ü` to `U` If I convert `çağdaş` to `cagdas` then my URL looks like this `.com/topic/cagdas.html`

I have used `cagdas` in SQL queries to select the proper row, but in the database, it is stored as `çağdaş` not `cagdas`. What can I do to remedy this, so that the database stores my dynamic URL in the converted form, as `cagdas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store both `çağdaş` and `cagdas` in the database table.